# PHP dynamic link using button

Tags: php

I want to integrate PHP dynamic link using button but code not working properly here is my link

```
<a href="start-exam.php?page=category&category='.$row["category"].'">'.$row["category"].'</a>
```

the code i have implemented is

```
echo'<button class="button button4" onClick="window.location.href="start-exam.php?page=category&category='.$row['category'].'">'.$row['category'].'</button>';
```

but this is not returning the url link.

Comment: what do you mean "... but code not working properly" ? what is the result?

Answer (score 0):

Use slash

```
echo "<button class='button button4' onClick=\"window.location.href='start-exam.php?page=category&category=".$row['category']."'\">".$row['category']."</button>";
```

Answer (score 0):

echo "<button class='button button4' onClick="window.location.href='start-exam.php?page=category&category=".$row['category']."'">".$row['category']."";